# Deleting Shared Drives with Drive API using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

This might be a hard one to solve and the answer might just be guidance on who to contact to get my issue fixed.

Basically, I need to delete some shared drives on Google Drive. I know that the shared drives need to be empty before they can be deleted.

I emptied the Shared drives by listing all of the files in the drive, and then deleting them in order from the furthest away to root drive folder. Once the file delete was completed, I then proceeded to delete the Shared drives.

This worked great, but a few drives (out of a lot) will not delete because they claim that they have "children" files in them.

I just run the files.list() script to bring the any files that slipped through back. Big problem though, zero files come back.

I go into the drives themselves and they have no files in them.

I rerun the Delete Shared script and the error message still claims that there are children in the drives.

How can I find these phantom files so I can delete them? Or is this something wrong on google's end?

See my code below for more information on what I am trying to do.

**List all Files in a Drive**

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(keyfile_dict=[json key file dictionary],
                                                               scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')

delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated([email of drive organizer])

user_drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials, cache_discovery=False)

file_id = []
name = []
page_token = None
while True:
    response = user_drive.files().list(corpora='drive',
                                       includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                       supportsAllDrives=True,
                                       driveId=[Shared Drive ID],
                                       fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                       pageSize=1000,
                                       pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        file_id.append(file.get('id'))
        name.append(file.get('name'))

    page_token= response.get('nextPageToken', None)

    if page_token is None:
        break
```

**Delete Shared Drives**

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(keyfile_dict=[json key file dictionary],
                                                               scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')

delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated([email of drive organizer])

user_drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials, cache_discovery=False)

user_drive.drives().delete(driveId=[Shared Drive ID]).execute()
```

Comment: Hello, have you been able to fix your issue? It seems to be related to propagation. Please let me know, thanks

Comment: @carlesgg97 - No, the problem has not been fixed.

Comment: I have unsuccessfully attempted to reproduce your issue.. If you are entitled to it (G Suite paid) I suggest you [contact G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)